# Django: [Object object] returned instead of django view array

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am having a little bit of trouble with my django project. Let's say, for example, I have a view written up to pull data from the database and return an array of names for a phonebook. When I put the returned data (phonebook contacts array) into an alert, the names come up fine, ex: "Adam", "Brittany", etc. When I console.log the returned data, the item names also are returned ("Adam", "Brittany", etc.). Using javascript, I am trying to get the data to display inside of a td cell, just the individual item names, so that there is a div for Adam, a div for Brittany, etc. Unfortunately, instead of displaying the contact names, my code is displaying [Object object] multiple times. How do I get the contact name to take place of [Object object]? Why is [Object object] appearing instead? Thank you for any help you can provide.

My code is as follows:

/models.py:

```
class phonebook(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=200)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

/views.py:

```
def phonebook_home(request):
    global phonebook
    phonebook = phonebook.objects.order_by('name')

try:
    indexStart = int(request.GET.get('indexStart'))
    indexEnd = indexStart + 3
    next_three_contacts = phonebook.objects.order_by('name')[indexStart:indexEnd]

    serializer = contactSerializer()
    data = serializer.serialize(next_three_contacts)


    contact_count = phonebook.objects.count()
    moreAvailable = ''
    if indexEnd + 3 <= contact_count: 
        moreAvailable = 'more_than_two'
    elif indexEnd + 2 <= contact_count:
        moreAvailable = 'two_more'
    else:
        moreAvailable = 'no_more'
    return JsonResponse({'returned_contacts': data, 'moreAvailable': moreAvailable})
except:
    pass
```

/Serializers.py:

```
from django.core.serializers.python import Serializer 

class contactSerializer(Serializer):
    def end_object(self, obj):
        self._current['id'] = obj._get_pk_val()
        self.objects.append( self._current )
```

/main.js:

```
function generateCard(contactNameC, iconC) {
    var card = "<td class='tablecells'><a class='tabletext' href='#'><span class='fa "
            + iconC + " concepticons'></span><h2 class='header'>" + contactNameC
            + "</h2><p><span class='fa fa-chevron-circle-right'></span></p></a></td>";
    return card;
}


var indexLast = 9;
$(".showmorebutton").click(function() {
    var config = {
        type: 'GET',
        url: SUBMIT_URL,
        data: {
            indexStart: indexLast
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data, textStatus_ignored, jqXHR_ignored)  {
            var moreAvailable = data.moreAvailable;
            var contacts = data.returned_contacts;
            var contactNameLoop = $.each(contacts, function(idx, obj) {
                    console.log(obj.name);
                    alert(obj.name)
                }); 

            if (moreAvailable === "more_than_two") {
                $("table").append("<tr></tr>");
                for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                var contactName = contactNameLoop[i]
                var icon = "fa facogs";
                $("table tr:last").append(generateCard(contactName, icon));
                }
            }
        }
    };
    $.ajax(config);
    indexLast += 3; 
});
```

edit:

I also made sure to import the proper modules/files into each python file.

Comment: Log all of `obj` to the console and see what the structure is.

Comment: @DanielRoseman When I do that it displays the next three contact names 3 times each.   Ex:   Joe    Sarah    John   Joe   Sarah    John   Joe    Sarah     John

Comment: Screenshot example:  http://postimg.org/image/v6xlqtizh/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your iterations will never yield 1 name at a time since your `$.each` is iterating over all of the contacts.

You should move your `generateCard` function within your contacts iteration and use the `obj` variable instead of passing the entire array (passing the entire array will either output undefined or [object Object]) into your `generateCard` function.

```
$.each(contacts, function(idx, obj) {
    var icon = "fa facogs";
    $("table tr:last").append(generateCard(obj, icon));
});
```

Complete but contrived example and assuming a probably faulty json structure.

```js
var contacts = [
  {name: 'henrik'},
  {name: 'sanaz'},
  {name: 'esther'},
];

var generateCard = function (obj, icon) {
  return "<tr><td>"+obj.name+'</td></tr>';
};
$("table").append("<tr></tr>");
$.each(contacts, function(idx, obj) {
    var icon = "fa facogs";
    $("table tr:last").append(generateCard(obj, icon));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table></table>
```

***Update***:

Your problem lies in your `generateCard` function, change `contactNameC` to `contactNameC.name`.

Comment: Hi! I refactored the AJAX call code and fixed it so now it returns one item at a time. Instead of returning [Object object] 3 times, it now displays it once. I updated my main.js file as stated above in the question. Do you know why it is still happening even after passing one item at a time?

Comment: It all depends on how `generateCard` function looks like. It's most likely in there.

Comment: Hmm, okay. I added in my code for the generateCard function up top if you don't mind taking a look at it, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for your help! It all makes sense now.